# How to do dependency injection when defining controller via a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There's a controller `medicineAutocomplete` that I declared within a directive. Now I want to inject $http into the controller but I can't figure out the right way to do it. I did this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
app.directive('medicineAutocomplete', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'medicine-autocomplete.html',
    controller: medicineAutocomplete,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  };
 });

medicineAutocomplete.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']; //is this right? 

function medicineAutocomplete ($timeout, $q, $http, $scope) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to inject all dependencies as per `medicineAutocomplete` function and they should be in the same order.

```
medicineAutocomplete.$inject = ["$timeout","$q", "$http", "$scope"];

function medicineAutocomplete ($timeout, $q, $http, $scope) {
...
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!I didn't add them to the dependency list initially because my application worked fine without it. I wonder how that works.

Comment: yes. you can work without injecting dependencies using `$inject`. But if you minify your application then angular can't identify which dependency is which. That is why we injecting the same dependence as a string using `$inject`.